# Not able to find Snackbar of Android app in Appium automation

Tags: android, appium, ui-automation, android-uiautomator, appium-android

I have a ToDo Android app which shows a Snackbar whenever a new ToDo is saved. In my automation test I am not able to capture the Snackbar so I tried with following xpath `driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@text='TO-DO saved']").isDisplayed()` and also tried `driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().text(\"TO-DO saved\")").isDisplayed()` but didn't get success.

Can anybody help me to get the Android Snackbar element in appium?

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that it happens only when the Snackbar contains action button, when it doesn't, Appium finds it very fast.
I still didn't find any solution.

Comment: In the absence of a definit solution (the other answer is a "try...") , I will accept this as a "partial" answer, contributing observation and analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Snackbar is element that appears only in certain condition and often for a short period of time.

You can try catching it with **FluentWait**:

```
FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
wait.until(visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@text='TO-DO saved']")));
```

Default polling period is **500 milliseconds**, should be enough in most cases.

Still think its better to replace xpath locator with id, probably you have to add `resource-id` for snackbar if its not in place.

Comment: I tried your solution but still getting the same error. Could you please provide me an example?

Comment: What error do you exactly get? Post stacktrace + exact code snippet + appium server & java-client library version. That will help

Comment: Appium is not able to get the Snackbar, it is appearing for few seconds. At the time of verification the Snackbar disappeares. When I increase the visibility duration of Snackbar, it worked. Getting Following error: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //*[@text='TO-DO saved'] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:81)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:271)

Comment: One thing you could do instead of increasing the life of the snack bar is use `WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, long timeOutInSeconds, long sleepInMillis)
` and specify the `sleepInMillis` to be smaller (10 worked for me). Effectively you are polling more often so there is a better chance the snackbar is present. The opposite of the solution in your comment above.